# Multiple Icons Showing

Tags: atom-editor

At first, this question shouldn't be that hard, but I don't know how to solve it.

I'm experimenting with Font-Awesome and everything works fine, except that it won't display just one icon.

Inside the Hml-Editor (Atom):

```
<body>
<div class="list">
 <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-home"</i><span>test</span></a>
</div><!--list-->
</body>
```

Inside the Browser:

```
<body>
<div class="list">
 <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-home" <="" i=""><span>test</span></i></a><i class="fa fa-fw fa-home" <="" i="">
</i></div><!--list--><i class="fa fa-fw fa-home" <="" i="">
</i>
</body>
```

Why's there more code in the Browser?
*the code is saved with the Atom-Editor and this appears also in a freshly opened Chrome-window (same with Firefox)*

Is this even a Browser problem?

After all this seems awkward but thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML is invalid, the opening `i` element never gets closed.

Try this:

```
<body>
  <div class="list">
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-home"></i><span>test</span></a>
  </div><!--list-->
</body>
```

Consider installing [`htmlhint`](https://atom.io/packages/linter-htmlhint) to get notified about invalid HTML.

Comment: I have this already installed.

But so much thanks,
I should consider to pay more atttention to the html-highliting. :)